# Robot Framework - Run Keyword If with Execute Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, robotframework

I'm trying to execute javascript and returning a value with `run keyword if` or something like that. But it gives error as expected. How can I pass this situation. Example code block:

```
Run Keyword If '${COUNTRY}'=='ES' ${income} Execute Javascript return $('#income').val();
```

Comment: could you explain more of your situation and share the error message you get? what does this have to do with automated tests?

Comment: I'm using "${income} Execute Javascript return $('#income').val();" part in some of my test cases. But I want to use same code with an if condition. When executing this as I shared below, it gives an error as "Variable '${income}' not found."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[Run keyword if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If)" requires a keyword after the condition; you've specified a variable name. To save the result of the keyword, the variable name must be in the first cell of the row:

```
${income}    run keyword if    '${COUNTRY}'=='ES' 
...    Execute Javascript return $('#income').val();
```